# android textview auto fit in linearlayout

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-linearlayout

I want to fit height textsize at linearlayout
but My textsize is very big so I couldn't fit height textsize in linearlayout

so I found the a way but It's very complicated

MainActivity.java

```
LinearLayout linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
linearLayout1.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED,View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
TextView textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
textview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, linearLayout1.getMeasuredHeight());
```

activity.xml (vetical)

```
<LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:gravity="center">

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="text"

     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Did you know simple another way?

Comment: use viewtreeobserver on textview after fixing text based on textview height fix linearlayout height programmatically

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions correct, you can use library for that. As an example, this can be taken: 
https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview

Update: or use this one https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AutoFitTextView.

Hope it will help you.